# Why is MooTools JSON.encode() returning "$caller":null?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have created a new class using MooTools. 
My class looks like this

**Updated:**

```
var c=new Class({
    a:'',
    b:'',
    c:'',
    d:'',
initialize:function(ee){
this.e=ee;
},
buildJSON:function()
{
var cInstance=new c(this.e);
cInstance.a=this.a;
cInstance.b=this.b;
cInstance.c=this.c;
cInstance.d=this.d;

return (JSON.encode(cInstance));
}
});

var x=new c("action");
x.a="Hello a";
x.b="Hello b";
x.c="Hello c";
x.d="Hello d";

alert (x.buildJSON());​
```

This is pretty a straightforward class. Now if you try it, there is an extra key on the JSON:

```
"$caller":null,
"caller":null
```

Comment: can you post this on jsfiddle?

Comment: here
http://jsfiddle.net/NNf5M/

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mootools-users/bJ5HiHnm-VU/i4LZaLmTs2EJ here is post with someone who had the same issue. HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$caller` and `caller` are both properties added by MooTools Class.

They exist to assist in the use of the `parent` method. You should clone the object and clean out the unnecessary properties before using `JSON.encode` on the class instance.

You could clone `this` and delete `$caller` and `caller` from the clone.

```
var c=new Class({
    a:'',
    b:'',
    c:'',
    d:'',

    initialize: function(ee) {
        this.e=ee;
    },

    buildJSON: function() {
        var data = Object.clone(this);
        delete data.$caller;
        delete data.caller;

        return (JSON.encode(data));
    }
});

var x=new c("action");
x.a="Hello a";
x.b="Hello b";
x.c="Hello c";
x.d="Hello d";

alert (x.buildJSON());​
```